# wget a release file from Github from a private repo

Tags: github, wget

```
wget --header 'Authorization: token PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE' https://github.com/<USER>/<REPO>/releases/download/<TAG>/<FILENAME.zip>
```

This download method doesn't work recently in release download (always 404).
Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your [token format](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-03-31-authentication-token-format-updates-are-generally-available/) is the more recent one: `ghp_` for Personal Access Tokens, created with a [scope repo](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-oauth-apps/scopes-for-oauth-apps).

And, for testing, activate [2FA on your GitHub account](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/securing-your-account-with-two-factor-authentication-2fa/configuring-two-factor-authentication): it will be [mandatory soon anyway](https://thenextweb.com/news/how-to-enable-2fa-github-account).